# How debug output to logger instead console in hapijs?

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I have instantiated an hapi server like:

```
var server = new hapi.Server({debug:true});
```

And if I throw an error in a request handling function I get it on the console output. How can I send it through the events to allow to log it like configured on the hapi server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the built in [logging](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/logging)

```
request.log(['error', 'database', 'read']);
```

You can then configure [good](https://github.com/hapijs/good) or another plugin to parse those logs.